# ProGuard issues with Android Archieve(.aar) library

Tags: android-studio, proguard, aar

I've a library project which I want to distribute, in AAR format. I've applied ProGuard on it.

ProGuard settings works well if I use this lib as a module, but not when I use resulting AAR. Basically it fails with exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added Lmy/lib/package/name/R;" in Application project.

ProGuard is renaming one of my lib class to R, and I feel which is causing problem in Application project as R is used for Resources.

How do I specify proguard mapping in Studio to tell it not to rename to R.

**Update:**
after adding AAR file as a new module, am getting this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lmy/lib/package/name/R;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay then, answering myself.

Tried running ProGuard manually on .aar, worked with latest version v5.2.1. Didn't work with default version v4.7 which came with Studio v1.2.2. Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please mention how you ran it on .aar file?

Comment: I did use android.pro example file supplied with ProgGuard v5.2.1. Supplied my dependency jars with '-libraryjars', input .aar as '-injars', output .aar as '-outjars'. Also had to add .aar specific proguard rules in the same .pro file. Manually added proguard.txt in the input .aar. Used command 'proguard.bat @android.pro' (on Windows). Hope this helps.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this automatically as part of a gradle build?

Comment: It works automatically with Android Studio now. don't remember since which version it has started to work.